# tmux after start

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

Can I configure *tmux* so it will after running *tmux* automatically opens two windows named *src* and *cmd*?
I always type after starting it:

<kbd>prefix + c</kbd>, <kbd>prefix + ,</kbd>src<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

<kbd>prefix + c</kbd>, <kbd>prefix + ,</kbd>cmd<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

I'd like to automate this.

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your particular case the following would do:

```
tmux new-session -n src -d \; new-window -n dst \; attach
```

A more general way would be to use the `source-file` command, e.g.

```
tmux new-session -d \; source-file FILE_WITH_TMUX_COMMANDS
```

Where FILE_WITH_TMUX_COMMANDS might contain:

```
rename-window src
new-window
rename-window dst
previous-window
attach
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain `-d` option? man page says `If -d is used, -x and -y specify the size of the initial window (80 by 24 if not given).` and what is the purpose of `attach` in the end? I haven't understood it much from man pages.

Comment: This will be already off topic, but would you please know why this ends with error when I run the command with `-c vim`?

Comment: `-d` makes tmux start in detached mode, this was the only way I found that allows you to send additional commands to the just started `tmux`. The `attach` then attaches the current terminal to the recently started `tmux`.

Comment: `-c vim` works when it is run with `tmux -c vim`. For the FILE_WITH_TMUX_COMMANDS solution above, this can be done with something like `send-key "vim\n"`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd similar need, But different.

I runs three sessions, each having different set of windows (programs) running on it.

If its adapted to your case, then

put `$sh .tmuxer &` in `~/.xinitrc`;  this will create everything for you, next time you attach to tmux, you will get what you want.

`.tmuxer` is a bash script with `u+x` privilage

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                             

tmux new-session -d -s default                                                                                                                     

tmux new-window -t default:1 -n 'src' '<you can give a command to run here>'                                                                                                               
tmux new-window -t default:2 -n 'cmd' 'top'                                                                                                       

tmux select-window -t default:1                                                                                                                          
tmux attach-session
```

Well, this is a bit verbose, but you see how you can expand this in future to suite your evolving needs.

If you're interested, [my dotFiles](https://github.com/kra3/dot_files) are hosted on github.

Answer (score 1):

There's a supplemental tool called tmuxinator (found at https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator ) that allows you to do this. I would suggest checking it out.