# How start byobu with session splited horizontaly?

Tags: linux, tmux, byobu

All is in the title. I can't get the right ~/.byobu/window file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how to make this work with the `window` file as that seems to be dedicated to `screen`, but I may be wrong.

Anyway, the following works with `byobu` here (`tmux` backend):

```
byobu new-session -n NAME -d \; split \; attach
```

You may also want to take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38485/tmux-after-start).